# CakePHP: create custom submit button with CSS class

Tags: css, cakephp

I have this code

```
<?php echo $paypal->submit(__('Click here if this page appears for more than 5 seconds', true), $paypalData);?>
```

Which generates

```
<div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Click here if this page appears for more than 5 seconds" /></div></form>
```

Is there any way I can specify a class for the outer div so it does not use the 'submit' class? I am not sure where that even gets set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to change the class

```
$(".submit").toggleClass('submit newClass');
```